# Regular Expression Name test with alerts

Tags: javascript, regex

How do i test the name value in the textbox and use regular expressions to evaluate all characters a-z, A-Z and may not exceed 12 characters by using alert boxes?

```
function validateName()

{
    var character = getName();

    var reName = /^[A-Z]|[a-z]{0,12}$/;
    if (reName.test(character)) {
        alert("Valid Name ");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Name ");
    }

    return character;
};

function getName()
//var getName = function(box)
{
    var name = document.getElementById("aName").value;
    return name;
};

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =  "Name" + validateName();
```

Comment: Why not use ^[a-zA-Z]{0,12}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex can be just

```
var reName = /^[a-z]{0,12}$/i;
```

What it currently does is look for `[A-Z]` at the beginning of the string or `[a-z]{0,12}` at the end of the string. But that is not what you want. If you want your regex as is but in a correct way, you would want

```
/^([A-Z]|[a-z]){0,12}$/
```

but it is a overkill since you can just use `i` ignore case flag and use the regex, I've mentioned above.

Comment: @Heisenberg glad to have helped you :)